# Does Christianity claim that the Bible is God's only Word?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible, word-of-god

If yes, what is the reference for this?

By this logic, any book before the Bible like the Torah is not the word of God.

According to Islam, Torah is the book of prophet Moses and Bible is the book of prophet Jesus and Quran is the book of prophet Muhammad.

Comment: You seem to think that the Torah is not part of the Bible. If you think that, you're wrong. The first five books of the Christian Bible are the same as the first five books of the Jewish Bible. These five books are the Torah (also known as the Pentateuch, or the Books of Moses).

Comment: Has it occurred to you that it's all of the Word that anyone could understand well enough to write down.

Answer (score 15):

The assumption that you make is that the Bible is "Jesus' book." It may or may not be the "[Injil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_(Islam))." In fact, Jesus neither wrote nor actually authored any piece of the book. Indeed, unlike Muhammed, Jesus did not even receive the Word, but rather *was* the Word of God.  As John 1 tells us:

> 1 In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. 2 He was with God in the beginning. 3 Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made. 4 In him was life, and that life was the light of all mankind.  ... 14 The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us. We have seen his glory, the glory of the one and only Son, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth.

This is picked up in Hebrews, where the author states:

> 1 In the past God spoke to our ancestors through the prophets at many times and in various ways, 2 but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son, whom he appointed heir of all things, and through whom also he made the universe.

Indeed, while the Bible is our perfect guide to the nature of God, it is to be understood that the Word points us to God because God is holy.

That Jesus is the exclusive way of salvation is made clear by Jesus' first disciples, Peter and John.  When the Jewish High Priest brought them up on charges, they said of Jesus:

> Salvation is found in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given to mankind by which we must be saved. (Acts 4:12)

Furthermore, Jesus himself was clear that he was the exclusive one and only Word, saying in John 14:6:

> Jesus answered, "I am the Way and the Truth and the Life. No one comes to the Father except through me.

The fundamental distinction I am making is this - [Christians](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/what-is-mainstream-christianity) do not believe Jesus to be a prophet or a teacher. Christians believe him to be God. As God, he was "the Word" (a Greek term *Logos* that brings the fundamental idea of being the one through whom all things are created and given meaning.) Muhammed did not claim to be God. Jesus did. The exclusivity of the "Bible" as God's Word doesn't make sense, because Jesus is the point, not the book. Unlike Islam, we do not restrict our understanding of God's Word to a single language, nor do we venerate the Scriptures as Islam does. Instead, we believe that God is "the Word" and that Jesus is God, not a prophet

The Bible (and I say this as one who has an exceedingly high view of the authority of Scripture!) is not the "ONLY" word of God, because Jesus is the Word. Any would-be Scripture that denies this fundamental tenet of who Jesus is, is by definition, not a Christian Scripture. Jesus, being the fundamental Word, is the only test.

Unlike a prophet who merely is God's servant, as Christians, we make the audacious claim that God became flesh, dwelt among us, *loved* us, and saved us.  Jesus is not a messenger, but God.

Comment: Great answer, taking "the Word of God" in its Biblical context!

Comment: I did not say Jesus PBUH wrote Bible. I mean the messages of this book are originally from Jesus PBUH. thanks for your context but I could not understand what was their relation to question (the ONLY in question). also your misunderstandings about prophet of Islam can be answered.

Comment: @Ahmadi  The fundamental distinction I am making is this - Christians do not believe Jesus to be a prophet or a teacher. Christians believe him to be God.  Muhammed did not claim to be God. Jesus did. The exclusivity of the "Bible" as God's Word doesn't make sense, because Jesus is the point, not the book. Unlike Islam, we do restrict our understanding of God's Word to a single language, we do venerate the Scriptures as Islam does. Instead, we believe that God is "the Word" and that Jesus is God, not a prophet.  That's why I redirected your question to the claim of Jesus, not the Bible.

Comment: @AffableGeek I would like to point out that Jesus being God is NOT universally accepted by Christians - however the majority do.  Unitarians, Mormons, Rosicrucian, etc however do not.

Comment: @DanAndrews It is a fundamental tenet of Orthodoxy Christianity, since the Nicene Creed of 325 AD, that Jesus is "God from God, Light from Light, True God from True God, begotten not made, of one being with the Father."  Deviation from this is [rare](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/884/what-is-mainstream-christianity) and not indicative of what most people think of when they speak of Christianity. Indeed, to the (97.5% of Christians by your definition) those who do not subscribe to this are typically not considered Christian for this reason.

Comment: @AffableGeek are you sure Jesus PBUH himself claimed to be God? or this is what you heard from church? also high % of believe to something does not prove anything.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  It is [throughout](http://www.godonthe.net/evidence/said_god.htm) the book of John. In ch 14, for example, he tells Thomas "I and the Father are One."  In Matthew, he is accused of claiming he is God. In Mark, he commands the demons not to tell others he is God. Jesus is very, very explicit that he is God - indeed, if this question isn't already on the site, it should be.

Comment: Here's another [good essay](http://www.probe.org/site/c.fdKEIMNsEoG/b.4226717/k.5191/Jesus_Claims_to_be_God.htm) on the subject of Jesus saying he is God.

Comment: P.S.  As a Christian imam, I rarely accept anything "I heard in church." And as to the "high % of people means nothing," I agree. But, for simplicity's sake, if you are going to reject the Nicene Creed as the basis of Christianity, you should also reject the Quran as the basis of Islam, since its about as universal.

Comment: Those poor Arians from the [First Council of Nicaea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea#Arian_controversy)

Comment: There is a reason that Arianism is called a heresy.

Comment: Yes, John 10:30 (not 14) has Jesus (PBUH) saying "I and my Father are one"; but John 17:11 has him saying "Holy Father, keep through thine own name those whom thou hast given me that they may be one, as we are".  Since Jesus (PBUH) is here talking about his followers "being one", it's clear that by "being one", he means something other than being "the exact same entity".  Whatever he meant by "being one", it is not credible to say that he meant that he is the same being as God.  Moreover, Jesus denies omnipotence in John 5:30 ...

Comment: ... "I can of mine own self do nothing: as I hear, I judge: and my judgment is just; because I seek not mine own will, but the will of the Father which hath sent me".  (Quotes are KJV).

Comment: @DavidWallace Your trinitarian objection should probably be raised as a separate question

Comment: This is why questions and answers should be qualified as to their specific doctrinal traditions.

Comment: I'm amused by the debate in these comments. I've known a few denominations, ones with significant membership, that are recognized as Christian and yet don't believe Jesus IS God. But interestingly, few recall the Bible mentioning a man and woman being married and becoming one flesh. We are given no clarification whether or not the oneness is considered the same between God and Jesus. Perhaps because the concept is always taken too  literally with humans. In the end, does it matter?

Answer (score 9):

From the context and questions, the *real* question here seems to be:

> Does Christianity permit additional works, such as the Qu'ran (in particular), to be the word of God

Well, firstly, the *Bible* is not usually taken to be the word of God; it is written by humans, with the emphasis that those words were supposedly *inspired and steered* by God.

As for "does Christianity allow the Qu'ran as authentic": no, it does not, frankly. By simple logic: if a Christian believed the Qu'ran to be the true and authentic word of God, then they would need to follow those beliefs / instructions, which would mean: they were following Islam. This is clearly not the case; it could even be argued that the similarities between the *practices* of Christianity and Islam are at best superficial.

So: no.

Comment: thanks for your frank answer. may God and Jesus PBUH bless and reward you.

Comment: @Ahmadi as they will, it matters not to me; I'm *kafir* ;p

Comment: kafir means farmer. and means who covers on truth like farmer covers on seed. as I see you are not kafir. also you should know there are different versions of Islam most of people do not know. if one know wahhabism and twelver shia Islam well and compare them will know truth about real Islam.

Comment: @Ahmadi perhaps you could tell me the correct term for an unbeliever, then? (I am neither Christian nor Muslim - or anything else for that matter), and I happily and openly state that I believe in no god or gods. I was, however, raised in Christianity (Roman Catholicism) - so I'm familiar with, and interested in, the topic.

Comment: there are different categories of nonbeliever in Quran. they are called Mushrik, "those who do not believe in unseen", Mulhid, ... also there are some believers called kafir. in shia Islam there is no problem of one be atheist and they should be respected. please look this debate between Imam Sadiq as and atheists: http://www.al-islam.org/short/bk-alsadiq-science.htm and http://www.al-islam.org/mufaddal/ they are wonderful and are from God in fact.

Comment: @Ahmadi minor point: there's a difference between "believing in no god", and "not believing in a god" - the same difference as "innocent" vs "not guilty"; re "do you know" - indeed, the lack of definition of God is a huge problem for any *reasoned* discussion on the subject; allow to phrase it thus: no combination of definition and evidence has been presented that demonstrates, to me, the existence or necessity for any deity; re mushrik vs kaafir - definitions vary, for example: http://abdurrahman.org/aqeeda/diffmushrikkaafir.pdf

Comment: in twelver shia Islam there are many evidence and definition for knowing  God. but not a man in sky. mushrik is a category of kafir. mishrik is who associate anything with God. i.e. believes there are any God more than real God. like who worship idol. or who believes doctor heal is from doctor and not God. in fact he is considering divine power for doctor which is considered some kind of worshiping a God. or who believes divine power for money or magic or anything else. kafir is who know what is truth but does not obey it and hides it from others to know.

Comment: any non Muslim is considered kafir but there are different types and levels of kafir and each has different rules. Christians, Jews, atheists,.. are considered kafir but with different rules in Islam about each. there are many who do not know truth. some seek it and some not that are two different category. some consider them kafir and some not and call them unknowing people or oppressed people who could not find truth. Quran says: http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/4:97

Answer (score 5):

**The Word of God Cannot Be Changed**

When Christians use the word *Bible*, they are not merely referring to the New Testament, but to the Old Testament as well.  This includes the Torah.

As the Quran (as well as the Bible) affirms, **God's Word cannot be changed**.

> Perfect are the words of thy Lord in truthfulness and justice; **no man
>   can change His words**; He is the All-hearing, the All-knowing. S. 6:115
>   Arberry
>
> for them is good tidings in the present life and in the world to come.
>   **There is no changing the words of God**; that is the mighty triumph. S.
>   10:64 Arberry
>
> Recite what has been revealed to thee of the Book of thy Lord; **no man
>   can change His words.** Apart from Him, thou wilt find no refuge. S.
>   18:27 Arberry
>
> The grass withers, the flower fades, but the word of our God will stand forever.  Isaiah 40:8 ESV
>
> For truly, I say to you, until heaven and earth pass away, not an iota, not a dot, will pass from the Law until all is accomplished.  Matthew 5:18 ESV

So, because we know God's Word cannot be changed, we know that we can have confidence in the accuracy and reliability of the Old and New Testaments.

**Warnings from God's Word**

Using, then, the Old and New Testament as a foundation, there are a few key points with regard to any new work that proclaims itself the Word of God.

- God's Word warns that there are many deceivers who will attempt to distort the truth about God.

  For many deceivers have gone out into the world, those who do not confess the coming of Jesus Christ in the flesh. Such a one is the deceiver and the antichrist.  2 John 1:7 ESV
- God's Word warns against the preaching of any other *gospel* other than the gospel of Jesus Christ.  In fact, it goes so far to say that **even if an angel of God should preach a different gospel, we are to reject it.**

  I am astonished that you are so quickly deserting him who called you in the grace of Christ and are turning to a different gospel— 7 not that there is another one, but there are some who trouble you and want to distort the gospel of Christ. 8 But even if we or an angel from heaven should preach to you a gospel contrary to the one we preached to you, let him be accursed. 9 As we have said before, so now I say again: If anyone is preaching to you a gospel contrary to the one you received, let him be accursed.  Galatians 1:6-9 ESV

**The Quran's Affirmation of the Bible**

The Quran itself affirms the Old and New Testaments:

> Dispute not with the People of the Book save in the fairer manner,
>   except for those of them that do wrong; and say, 'We believe in what
>   has been sent down to us, **and what has been sent down to you**; our God
>   and your God is One, and to Him we have surrendered.' S. 29:46 Arberry
>
> Then **We gave Moses the Book**, complete for him who does good, and
>   distinguishing every thing, and as a guidance and a mercy; haply they
>   would believe in the encounter with their Lord. **This is a Book We have
>   sent down, blessed; so follow it, and be godfearing;** haply so you will
>   find mercy; **lest you should say, 'The Book was sent down only upon two
>   parties before us,** and we have indeed been heedless of their study';
>   or lest you say, 'If the Book had been sent down upon us, we had
>   surely been more rightly guided than they.' Yet indeed a clear sign
>   has come to you from your Lord, and a guidance and a mercy; and who
>   does greater evil than he who cries lies to God's signs, and turns
>   away from them? We shall surely recompense those who turn away from
>   Our signs with an evil chastisement for their turning away. S.
>   6:154-157 Arberry

**Conclusion**

So, whenever any other book is offered as another Word from God, we need to be very careful and "test the spirits to see whether they are from God, for many false prophets have gone out into the world." (1 John 4:1 ESV)  Also, if any other book contradicts the Bible, then it is another gospel and must be rejected.

In the case of the Quran, it was actually claimed to be delivered to Muhammad by an *angel of God*.  God's Word gives us a very specific warning about such a claim.  The Quran contradicts the Bible and presents *another gospel*.

The Bible is God's Word--and God's Word cannot be changed.  Therefore, we must conclude that the Quran is *not* the Word of God, and that is why Christians do not accept it as such.

Comment: Excellent use of the Q'uran.  I was wanting to go to Surah 5, but I think your references are better :)

Comment: To draw out the question, then I would suggest: "Thus, if God's word cannot be changed, and the Bible and Qu'ran both claim to be the Word of God, logically, only one can be so."

Comment: @AffableGeek Yes, and the Quran affirms the Old and New Testaments.

Comment: thanks. but your conclude is your own conclude. I need a reference from Bible saying ONLY Bible is word of God. also please consider probability of partially deviating bible during history by corrupted scholars. or misunderstanding Quran. both can be word of God in their "Original version" today there are different versions of bible and this proves it is possible original version changed in history.  but Quran is only one version.

Comment: Quran is talking about original Bible of Jesus PBUH himself and not today versions of bible.

Comment: Quoting the Qu'ran to support Christianity is just... bizarre. If you believe the Qu'ran is accurate and sacred, then you should follow Islam and all that comes with it. If you *don't* believe that it is accurate, then it doesn't matter whether it agrees or disagrees on this point. The Bible, for obvious reasons, makes no claim on the accuracy of the Qu'ran.

Comment: @Ahmadi If God's Word cannot be changed--and the Old and New Testaments and the Quran all affirm that--then the *modern* versions are unchanged.  Also, the Quran is most certainly not one version.  Muhammed himself verified two differing versions of the same Surah.  Also, all the manuscripts were collected after Muhammed's death to sythesize them all into one version.  We have no manuscripts prior to that, since they were destroyed.  So no one can ever conclusively state that all manuscripts prior to that match the current version.

Comment: @ahmadi Our question should not be whether or not the Bible proves it alone is the Word of God based on one method of evidence that we want.  Rather, it should be to ask whether or not God has authenticated the Bible and the Bible alone with whatever criteria He chose.  The answer to this question is in the affirmative.  The Bible alone is demonstrated to be the Word of God by 1) miracles, 2) prophecy, 3) the transformation of lives, and above all, 4) the resurrection of Jesus from the dead.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes Quran support Christianity and we believe it and we follow Christianity as well as Islam. Quran says Christianity was an incomplete version of Islam. but Quran always means original version of Christianity revealed to Jesus PBUH that can be partially different of what is in different versions of today bibles.

Comment: @Narnian according to Quran bible is not protected from change unlike Quran and in fact the reason of reveal of Quran is change of bible. "Muhammed himself verified two differing versions of the same Surah" this is not true. "all the manuscripts were collected after Muhammed's death" not true. I agree bible is word of God. my question is about ONLY.

Comment: @Ahmadi It seems you would need to disagree with the Quran to assert that the Bible is not protected from change.

Comment: @Ahmadi most accounts of the Qu'ran being bound into a single collection relate to shortly post-prophet, in particular Omer and the battle of Al-Yamamah spring to mind... am I mistaken? (yes, there were, it is said, scraps of the Qu'ran on any kinds of writing material available, but they were not *compiled*, so cannot be in any way verified). And yes, I know that technically it could be argued the first version of the Qu'ran is in the heads of those who memorised it under the prophet, but again: tricky to validate.

Comment: @ahmadi You should read up on this.   "In Sahih Bukhari, Vol. VI, #527, Umar noted that, despite the fact that Ubai was called the greatest reciter of the Quran by Muhammad, two of the Surahs in Ubai’s Quran were not put in Zaid’s codex."

Comment: @ahmadi Why were the previous manuscripts of the Quran destroyed after the compilation?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Quran

Comment: @ahmadi I really encourage you to read both sides of this issue.  There's a lot of evidence that it seems you have not been exposed to that bring the Quran into serious question.

Comment: @Narnian 1- that destroy is not considered legimate in shia Islam. 2- it was for difference in RECITATION METHOD of Quran and not any problem in text of Quran. there is no conflict about even one word of Quran before and after that compilation. it was for standard "RECITATION METHOD" (pronunciation) and it is not about text of Quran. even one word. Quran was memorized by hundreds of companions and written on animal skins at time of prophet and never was any conflict on TEXT of Quran.

Comment: @Ahmadi Again, I encourage you to read *both sides* of this issue.  Whenever we read only one side of an issue, we can miss a lot of things.  If something is true, it can withstand scrutiny.  I have read the Quran and some of the Book of Mormon, even though I don't believe either of these are the Word of God.  I'm sure you have read the Bible as well.  I'm just saying that it's really beneficial to look at both sides of the argument and all the evidence that is presented.

Comment: Makes me wonder what Scientology's take on this is.

Comment: @Narnian you're implying that the bible doesn't change.  That's not true.  One of the really things I like about the Quran is that it has remained in its original text.  Unfortunately it's in "old school" Arabic that most people don't know anymore.  However, the same cannot be said about the Bible else there would be no differences between KJV, NIV, ESV, etc.

Comment: Please consider making a chat of these comments.

Comment: @DanAndrews The different between the KJV, NIV, and ESV is English--not Greek, Hebrew, or Aramaic.  And a careful study will demonstrate the Quran is not as "original" as many are led to believe.

Comment: @Narnian The different translations to English is an example.  True, the other language versions of the bible are even more different.  Do you have anything to back up the claim that the Quran is not as "original" as some believe?  From what I understand, Muslims saw how the translation of the bible changed it slightly so they picked one and burnt the rest.  While it's not "original" they did draw a line in the sand and there were no changes after that.

Comment: @AffableGeek "Thus, if God's word cannot be changed, and the Bible and Qu'ran both claim to be the Word of God, logically, only one can be so." Replace Quran with Torah and you'd have the argument that the jews have.

Comment: @DanAndrews No, because the Torah is incomplete without the Messiah it foretells.  The Old Testament specifically prophecies a Messiah who dies right around 30 A.D.  It also speaks of a New Covenant that God will bring.  Thus, Malachi leaves us hanging until Jesus comes as its fulfillment.

Comment: @Narnian That is the Christian perspective.  Meanwhile the jews (today) wait for the Messiah.

Comment: @DanAndrews Well, today more and more Jews are coming to faith in Jesus as their Messiah--and many Muslims as well.  The argument could certainly be made that the Old and New Testaments are different and only one can be true, but such an argument would not be as powerful as that of the Quran and the Bible.  The New Testament fits with the Old, while the Quran differs greatly from them.  So, yes the argument could be made, but it wouldn't be a very good one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4687/discussion-between-dan-andrews-and-narnian)

Answer (score 4):

The [Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah) is part of the Bible: it is the first five books so is considered by Christians to be "the word of God".

Regarding the Bible being the word of God first, a verse regular quoted by Christians is [2 Timothy 3:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy+3:16&version=NIV):

> All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness.

Regarding the Bible being complete (i.e. no written* "words of God" following), [Revelation 22:18-19](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2022:18-19&version=NIV) is often quoted:

> I warn everyone who hears the words of the prophecy of this scroll: If anyone adds anything to them, God will add to that person the plagues described in this scroll. And if anyone takes words away from this scroll of prophecy, God will take away from that person any share in the tree of life and in the Holy City, which are described in this scroll.

*(although some dispute this and say it is only referring to the last book of the Bible, Revelation itself)*.

<sub>*Some Christian (eg Pentacostal) churches practice "words of knowledge" which are "oral" words of God. It is a whole different topic, but Pentacostals would not accept them as valid if they contradicted Scripture.</sub>

Comment: This is not a great answer because, apart from the Revelation quote, I cannot say why Christians considered the written word of God closed with the Bible. Indeed, some groups identifying themselves as Christians (eg Mormons) *do* have additional books.

Comment: agree! I have no doubt Bible is world of God. but my question is about reference for "ONLY"

Comment: Downvoting because...?

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that Christianity does not consider itself a wholly and entirely different religion from Judaism. Instead Christian belief is that God worked his will through his Chosen People, the Jews, promising them a Saviour (Messiah) in due course. However when that Saviour was sent, some accepted him and some did not. Those that did became Christians, and those that did not continued to call themselves Jews.

Up until the time of Jesus, God acted through the Jews. This included revealing himself to them, and causing to be written holy books of prophecy, teaching and history - the Jewish scriptures. Christians consider those writings to be just as much written by God as anything written in the time of Jesus. The teachings of Jesus do override the Jewish scriptures, because God made a new revelation through him - however they are still considered holy writings, as they reveal God's will for his people *at the time they were written*.

The Christian Bible therefore contains two parts - the Jewish scriptures are referred to as the Old Testament (more accurately Old Convenant) and the writings about Jesus are the New Testament (New Covenant).

Comment: thanks for your explain. I had misunderstanding that Bible is only book of Jesus PBUH. this what Quran says. Quran call book or Moses PBUH Torah (تورات) and book of Jesus PBUH Bible (انجیل Injeel) and book of David PBUH Zaboor (زبور)

Comment: @Ahmadi To clarify - "Moses" wrote the first five books of the Old Testament. Other Jews wrote other books (David, for example, write much of the Psalms).  In the New Testament, Matthew, Mark (through the Apostle Peter), Luke (who travelled with Paul), and John wrote the Gospels.  Paul, Peter, James, Jude, John, and an unnamed author of Hebrews wrote the rest of the New Testament.

Comment: What does it mean by old testaments no longer apply? In which case we no longer need to stone adulterous couple. For that same reason, buttsex is okay too?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good and interesting answers here, but one Catholic perspective is missing.

Bl. Pope John Paul II's [*Theology of the Body*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932645349) made it clear that God one way God speaks through us is through His creation. To be sure, Creation itself, is in the Bible, but the Bible doesn't say. "Men shall be X because I, the LORD your God created them this way and woman shall be X because I, the LORD your God created them that way".  It does say "Men shall *DO* this and women shall *DO* that", but doesn't go into the inherent qualities of the sexes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write a separate answer for what I believe is a separate question. You ask if the Bible is the ONLY word of God. Most Christians would say 'absolutely yes', but the actual position is a little more complex than that. It is certainly true that mainstream Christianity has never acknowledged any additional scriptures, and most consider that the Bible is a 'closed canon', which means that no scriptures *can* be added to it. However the 'canon'  is only the acknowledged and approved list of God's writings. Could God cause to be written some other book for some reason? Yes he could. However he would not create a book that contained things *necessary for salvation*; i.e. it might contain useful teachings, but not things that a Christian *had* to accept in order to be a true Christian.

Comment: @Ahmadi "fabricated" is a very dangerous word to throw around; obviously they are different belief systems. By definition, Christians do not accept the Qu'ran as "true", therefore by Christian perspective, it is the Qu'ran that is fabricated. But let me turn it around: if someone new claimed some new revelation that they think should be added to the Qu'ran, you would call them liar or heretic. Christianity is no different.

Comment: @MarcGravell OK I deleted my comment. thanks. but I need some original Christian reference for this "ONLY".

Comment: Revelation 22:18-19 is not a good source here. When Revelation was written the author had no idea that it would be incorporated into The Biible, still less that it would be the last book in it. It his highly unlikely that the author intended the passage to refer to all scripture - just to that particular book.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think this comment deserve to be a separate answer. but it is about adding to this particular book. but about a new book. similarly no one can add even one word to Quran.